# Php DateTime Временное отклонение

Tags: php

При получении даты и последующей прибавкой 3х дней, возникает временное отклонение на 1 час.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+3 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Помогите получить корректное время!

Comment: Часовой пояс виноват.

Comment: У меня не возникает. Не могли бы вы в примере вместо текущей даты указать такую, на которой возникает? Плюс дополнить тем, что выводит echo.

Comment: Да тут дело собственно либо в локальной системе либо в DateTime, т.к. при $date = new DateTime(), в $date - время уже опаздывает на час.